# Uploading file via PUT method in react-native

Tags: javascript, curl, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, react-native

I am trying to upload file(image) from my react-native app to backend server. The RESTFUL backend server accepts file send via PUT method on a specific url. I am stuck on react-native trying to find the proper way to send file via PUT method. 
I am trying to replicate behavior of 
`curl -X PUT -T "/path/to/file" "http://myputserver.com/puturl.tmp"` 
I found [XMLHttpRequest method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileUpDown#HTTP_PUT) of doing this on a browser but won't work on react-native. Have anyone gone through this please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
   alert(responseJson)
})
.catch((error) => {
 console.error(error)
})
```

[reference](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#fetch) 
 [reference 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options)

Answer (score 0):

## Fetch

Use the [fetch api](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org), which is supported by React Native.
Below is an example of the [official documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#fetch).

Fetch supports `PUT`, according to the [specs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#methods).

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

Comment: The example you've provided is of POST. I was expecting examples of PUT method. I have gone through specs and know fetch supports PUT.

Comment: the question is about uploading a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PUT like the answer above. You might be missing the 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'.

```
 const config = {
     method: 'PUT',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'SECRET_OAUTH2_TOKEN_IF_AUTH',
     },
     body: data,
    }
```

Some more information in this blog post:
http://snowball.digital/Blog/Uploading-Images-in-React-Native